# What is the Indian government doing to combat rape?

Tags: india, crime

Rape is a very [prominent issue](https://www.thedailybeast.com/whats-really-behind-indias-rape-crisis) in India for the last few years. In Delhi, [5 women get raped each day](https://www.indiatimes.com/news/india/in-delhi-the-rape-capital-of-india-five-women-were-raped-each-day-in-first-quarter-of-2018_-344881.html).
[Recently](http://www.india.com/news/india/rape-sexual-assault-cases-in-india-a-timeline-till-it-stops-3009077/), [two girls](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/asia_pacific/an-8-year-old-girls-gang-rape-and-murder-trigger-new-outrage-over-indias-rape-culture/2018/04/18/15b66724-4254-11e8-b2dc-b0a403e4720a_story.html?noredirect=on&utm_term=.5a17c840fa52) were [raped](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/yet-another-girl-raped-killed-in-etah/articleshow/63853247.cms) and tortured to death which attracted a huge public outcry. Yet, there more rape going on as we speak<sup>[1](https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/8-month-old-girl-raped-killed-in-indore-basement-suspect-seen-on-cctv-1840691), [2](https://www.indiatimes.com/news/india/missing-latvian-woman-was-drugged-raped-before-murder-in-kerala-2-arrested-344762.html), [3](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/05/05/asia/india-rape-killing/index.html), [4](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/05/07/asia/second-india-rape-attack-intl/index.html), [5](http://indianexpress.com/article/cities/mumbai/mumbai-5-yr-old-girl-raped-by-minor-neighbour-5167357/)</sup>.

BJP and other right wing activists demonstrated [in support of alleged rapists](https://www.dailyo.in/voices/unnao-rape-kathua-rape-sexual-assault-narendra-modi-amit-shah-bjp/story/1/23489.html). PM [Modi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narendra_Modi) reportedly [downplayed](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2018/apr/17/modis-government-fails-to-act-on) rapes.

What is the Indian government doing to combat rape?

Comment: I edited the question to remove the word "epidemic", because it is an unnecessarily sensationalist misnomer.

Comment: We understood the question. You don't need to update it whenever there is another news report about a rape in India.

Comment: I am afraid that five raped women per day in Delhi is a huge underestimation. If it was the case, one could conclude that India is not suffering from more rapes than other countries. For instance, in France, there are about 200 rapes per day for a population of 67M. The same ratio for the 20M Delhi would mean about 60 rapes per day. https://www.planetoscope.com/Criminalite/1497-viols-en-france.html

Answer (score 10):

The country has been witnessing massive protests in light of the two most recent incidents of rape crimes, especially the rape and murder of an eight year old female in Kathua, Jammu and Kashmir. The involvement of a ruling party mla in the other case in the state of Uttar Pradesh has further infuriated the public.

The Union Cabinet as of today (April 21, 2018) has approved an ordinance to allow courts to award death penalty to those convicted of raping children up to 12 years of age.

In addition to amendments in the Protection of Children from Sexual Offences (POCSO) Act to ensure catial punishment, the ordinance also seeks provisons for:

- Maximum sentence term for rape crimes
- Speedy trials by setting up new fast track court
- Specifying a period for completion of investigation and trials
- Restriction clauses on anticipatory bail for the accused if the victim is under 16 years
- Providing proper forensic kits to the police stations and setting up forensic labs to aid timely investigation
- NCRB (National Crimes Records Bureau) to also maintain a sexual offenders data

[Union Government approves death penalty for rape of children](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/union-cabinet-approves-ordinance-for-death-penalty-for-rape-of-children-5146104/)

Comment: kindly attach appropriate citations.

Answer (score 6):

- Change and clarify the law (in 2013)
- Introduce a "fast track court" system to prioritise and speed rape trials.
- Make hospitals legally required to offer free health care to rape victims.
- Raise the age of consent to 18.
- Include in the *saathiya* public education for adolescents' relationship education including education on the concept of "consent".
- Training for police in investigating rape accusations.

There is a question of whether there is a rape epidemic at all. Certainly rape accusations and sexual assault accusations have not risen much, and are much lower than in Europe or the USA, but under-reporting makes these figures very questionable, it isn't clear if the rises are due to a rise in rape, the 2013 changes to to he definition of rape, or a rise in reporting.

Comment: Are those 6 points your proposals or facts? If those are facts, then kindly attach appropriate citations.

Comment: @yahoo.com, while I agree that citations would improve the answer, the fact that James' first point is about a change in the law, from 2013, should make it clear that he is implying that these changes have already happened.